# wine32 и debian10

Tags: debian, wine

При попытке запуска виндовских программ на Debian Testing через wine он требует wine32, которая не ставится.

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет wine32 недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «wine32» не найден кандидат на установку
```

Архитектуру i386 добавлял. `apt -f install` делал.

Если скачать wine32 в виде deb файла и ставить через gdebi - он ругается на несовместимость с библиотекой `libc6 2.28`

Вот что получилось на выходе

```
$ lsb_release -a; head -n 30 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
deb [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free

deb [arch=amd64] http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free


deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ testing main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
i386
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update`? В смысле дополнительную архитектуру добавляли именно так и списки пакетов обновили?

Comment: sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update? В смысле дополнительную архитектуру добавляли именно так и списки пакетов обновили? Да, именно так.

Comment: 1. зарегистрируйтесь наконец, а затем прочтите: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). 2. приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод команды: `$ lsb_release -a; head -n 30 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Answer (score 1):

в файле `/etc/apt/sources.list` почти у всех источников пакетов зафиксирована архитектура — `[arch=amd64]`.

для того, чтобы использовать пакеты других архитектур, я бы рекомендовал убрать архитектурную привязку у этих источников:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free

deb [arch=amd64] http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

удалив подстроку `[arch=amd64]`, чтобы строки выглядели примерно так:

```
deb http://...
deb-src http://...
```

после этого надо будет обновить список пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt update
```

и ставить то, что вам нужно.

---

> Если скачать wine32 в виде deb файла и ставить

хотя ход ваших мыслей и понятен, но абсолютно ошибочен. так делать не надо.